# Emacs Lisp spawning subprocesses with custom environmental variables

Tags: linux, emacs, lisp, elisp

Basically I want to spawn a process changing its working directory.
My idea was to spawn a process and set the PWD enviroment variable.

There's a way to obtain something like that?

(virtually I would like to change any of the environment variables for flexibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the `default-directory` variable before spawning your process.  Example:

```
(let ((default-directory "/tmp/"))
  (call-process "/bin/bash" nil "*scratch*" nil "-c" "echo working dir is $PWD"))
```

I ran this from my `*scratch*` buffer and the string `working dir is /tmp` was added to the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

This shows the default environment variables:

```
(shell-command "env")
```

and this shows how you could change them on a per-process basis:

```
(shell-command "PWD=/tmp env")
```

Answer (score 2):

`$PWD` is an environment variable that reflects the current working directory, not one that controls it.

According to the [Processes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html#Processes) section of the [Elisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/), the default directory for a spawned process is determined by the value of [default-directory](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html#index-default_002ddirectory-1859).  The environment of the spawned process is the same as that of the Emacs session, which you can modify with [setenv](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html#index-setenv-3738).  You can also specify environment variables which are used solely for spawned processes via the [process-environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html#index-process_002denvironment-3739) variable.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, to get python subprocesses to behave the way that I wanted (apparently completely thinking that they were in the specified directory) I had to do:

```
(let* ((default-directory (find-correct-dir))
       (process-environment (cons (format "PWD=%s" default-directory)
                                  process-environment)))
  (do-the-subprocess-thing))
```

Or, if I wanted to throw away the rest of the environment:

```
(let* ((default-directory (find-correct-dir))
       (process-environment (list (format "PWD=%s" default-directory))))
  (do-the-subprocess-thing))
```

That is, I needed to set *both* `default-directory` and `process-environment`, and to the same value.